# Does package compiled partially? How to prevent this?

Tags: perl

I have code (some lines are removed):

```
package MaitreD::Command::bank_statement;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Command';

sub run {
    ...
    my $payments =  read_file( $file );   # line 58
    ...
}

use XBase;                                # line 174
sub read_file {
    ...
}

1;
```

I run my application. And then do two http requests to this app. Controller runs this command as:

```
$c->app->commands->run( bank_statement => $upload );
```

I get next error (this one is expected):

```
Can't locate XBase.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XBase module) (@INC contains: /opt/monkeyman/lib /opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5 /opt/monkeyman/lib /opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1 /opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /opt/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5 /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1 /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1/x86_64-linux /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1 .) at /opt/monkeyman/lib/MaitreD/Command/bank_statement.pm line 174.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/monkeyman/lib/MaitreD/Command/bank_statement.pm line 174.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 2620) line 1.
```

But when I did second request I got different error:

```
Undefined subroutine &MaitreD::Command::bank_statement::read_file called at /opt/monkeyman/lib/MaitreD/Command/bank_statement.pm line 58.
```

How `MaitreD::Command::bank_statement::run` could be run from controller if module `MaitreD::Command::bank_statement` compilation failed?

If understand correct the module `MaitreD::Command::bank_statement` was compiled partially to 174 line. So next http request to app can call `MaitreD::Command::bank_statement::run` and when 58 line is reached I get `Undefined subroutine &M::C::b::read_file called` because nothing is compiled after 174 line.

How to prevent partial compilation? 
I want if there are some errors occur then nothing from `MaitreD::Command::bank_statement` should be available

Comment: `sub foo { ... }` is equivalent to `BEGIN { *foo = sub { ... } }`. At best, you could clean the namespace (delete the contents of the package) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should be focusing on ensuring `use XBase` actually succeeds, beause presumably it's there for a reason and it's needed for the rest of the program to work.

Why does it fail? Fix that first and the partial compilation isn't a problem.

In this case, why can't perl find the module?

Is it possible the Command::bank_statement class isn't `use`d directly, but only when it's being run, so maybe the current working directory changed between the program start and the time `$c->app->commands->run( bank_statement => $upload );` was called?

If that's the case, try loading the command class earlier. e.g. add this to the Mojo application class (probably something like `lib/MaitreD.pm`:

`use MaitreD::Command::bank_statement;`